# Matrix block fields returning NULL when using MatrixBlock query

Tags: matrix, craft3, plugin-elementapi, query

```
$blocks = MatrixBlock::find()->relatedTo($entry)->all();
```

The above returns the correct blocks but all fields are returned as NULL.

I've read over at [GitHub](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1789) that we need to specify a fieldId param but can't seem to figure out how.  The below e.g. doesn't work:

```
$blocks = MatrixBlock::find()->relatedTo($entry)->fieldId([33])->all();
```

Help anyone?

Comment: Is your field id correct? You need to insert an id and not an array

Comment: @RobinSchambach Ah yes my field id was wrong...  I was adding the field id of the matrix block.  The right ID to add is the Matrix field id as defined in the Fields section.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The right Field ID to add is the `Matrix` field id as defined in the `Fields` section.  Do not use the ids of the matrix block fields.